# Is the the screw thread of a filter regulated by some standard?

Tags: filters

Is the the screw thread of a filter regulated by some standard? I am talking about round filter.
For example, is the ISO metric screw thread standard applicable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the real answer, but in lieu of someone who does, a quick search tells me that [apparently not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_filter#Threaded_round_filters), but that a [0.75mm thread pitch](http://photonotes.org/cgi-bin/photo-entry.pl?id=Threadpitch) is used by "most Japanese photographic manufacturers today".